# Function $f(n) = 2^{\omega(n)}\mu^2(n)$

Tags: number-theory, divisor-sum

Let 
$$f(n) = 2^{\omega(n)}\mu^2(n)$$, where $\omega(n)$ is number of distinct prime divisors of $n$ and $\mu(n)$ is Moebius function.

I want to simplify it.

As long as 
$$
\mu^2(n)=\sum_{d^2|n}\mu(d)
$$
and
$$
2^{\omega(n)}=\sum_{d|n}\mu^2(d)
$$
so
$$
f(n)=\sum_{d|n}\mu^2(d)\sum_{d^2|n}\mu(d)
$$
And I can't simplify it further. Is it possible?

Thanks.

NB. By "to simplify" I mean "to express in terms of divisors on $n$"

Comment: I can simplify it. We have $f(n)=0$, if $n$ is not squarefree, and $f(n)=2^{\omega(n)}$ otherwise.

Comment: Our two functions are multiplicative, and computing the values at prime powers is easy.

Comment: What do you mean by "simplify"? It seems your last equation is more complicated than the formula itself.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to "simplify" $f(n)$ is to consider that $f(n)$ is a multiplicative function (since both $2^{\omega(n)}$ and $\mu^2(n)$ are multiplicative functions) whose values on $p^k$ is $2$ if $k=1$, $0$ otherwise. This gives, for instance (assuming $\Re(s)>1$):
$$ \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{f(n)}{n^s}=\prod_{p}\left(1+\frac{2}{p^s}\right)\leq\prod_{p}\left(1+\frac{1}{p^s}\right)^2=\left(\frac{\zeta(s)}{\zeta(2s)}\right)^2.$$

Comment: Why would an inequality of Dirichlet series (that isn't even correct, since it assumes $s$ is real and positive) be helpful to the OP?

Comment: @GregMartin: Because it is helpful in evaluating the average/mean order of $f(n)$. I bet this is the reason to "simplify" $f(n)$.

Comment: I don't see any evidence of that ... but I'll accept a hearty "I told you so" if that turns out to be the case!